# Sharepoint Deploy web part error

Tags: sharepoint

When I try to deploy web part, I got the error " The solution needs to install assemblies in the GAC, Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify allowGacDeployment parameter in STSADM command (or GacDeployment in PowerShell)